# Famo.us not loading Constructor of Strip View in Timbre Example

Tags: triggers, view, slidetoggle, famo.us

I am working no Timbre View Example of Famo.us, and what I am trying to achieve is simply open the page by clicking on strip view options in the app and closing the Menu Drawer as soon as I click on the Strip View option

for achieving this functionality I've read the [Broad Cast and Listing](http://famo.us/guides/events) from the Famo.us documentation. and wrote the following code in my example.

1) created a function to Broadcasting from an event handler with emit method and called it in Constructor of the Strip View.

**Strip View:**

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    var View = require('famous/core/View');
    var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
    var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');
    var StateModifier = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');
    var ImageSurface = require('famous/surfaces/ImageSurface');
    var HeaderFooter = require('famous/views/HeaderFooterLayout');
    var FastClick = require('famous/inputs/FastClick');

    var check = true;
    Boolean(check);

    function StripView() {

        View.apply(this, arguments);

        _createBackground.call(this);
        _createIcon.call(this);
        _createTitle.call(this);

        _setListenersForStripView.call(this);
    }

    StripView.prototype = Object.create(View.prototype);
    StripView.prototype.constructor = StripView;

    StripView.DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
        width: 320,
        height: 55,
        angle: -0.2,
        iconSize: 32,
        iconUrl: 'img/strip-icons/famous.png',
        title: 'Famo.us',
        fontSize: 26,
        onload: 'StripView()'
    };

    function allFunctions()
    {
        _createBackground();
        _createIcon();
        _createTitle();
    }

    function _createBackground() {
        this.backgroundSurface = new Surface({
            size: [this.options.width, this.options.height],
            properties: {
                backgroundColor: 'black',
                boxShadow: '0 0 1px black'
            }
        });


        var rotateModifier = new StateModifier({
            transform: Transform.rotateZ(this.options.angle)
        });

        var skewModifier = new StateModifier({
            transform: Transform.skew(0, 0, this.options.angle)
        });

        this.add(rotateModifier).add(skewModifier).add(this.backgroundSurface);

        //  this.backgroundSurface.on("touchend", function(){alert("Click caught")})
    }

    function _createIcon() {
        var iconSurface = new ImageSurface({
            size: [this.options.iconSize, this.options.iconSize],
            content: this.options.iconUrl,
            pointerEvents: 'none'
        });

        var iconModifier = new StateModifier({
            transform: Transform.translate(24, 2, 0)
        });

        this.add(iconModifier).add(iconSurface);
        // iconSurface.on("click", function(){alert("Click caught")})
    }

    function _createTitle() {
        this.titleSurface = new Surface({
            size: [true, true],
            pointerEvents: 'none',
            content: this.options.title,
            properties: {
                color: 'white',
                fontFamily: 'AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBold',
                fontSize: this.options.fontSize + 'px',
                textTransform: 'uppercase',
                //  pointerEvents : 'none'
            }
        });

        var titleModifier = new StateModifier({
            transform: Transform.thenMove(Transform.rotateZ(this.options.angle), [75, -5, 0])
        });

        this.add(titleModifier).add(this.titleSurface);
    }

    function _setListenersForStripView() {
        this.backgroundSurface.on('touchend', function() {
            this._eventOutput.emit('menuToggleforStripView');
            alert('clicked on title');
        }.bind(this));
    }

    module.exports = StripView;
});
```

2) Then created a **Trigger** Method in App View

**App View:**

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    var View = require('famous/core/View');
    var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
    var Modifier = require('famous/core/Modifier');
    var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');
    var StateModifier = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');
    var Easing = require('famous/transitions/Easing');
    var Transitionable = require('famous/transitions/Transitionable');
    var GenericSync = require('famous/inputs/GenericSync');
    var MouseSync = require('famous/inputs/MouseSync');
    var TouchSync = require('famous/inputs/TouchSync');
    GenericSync.register({'mouse': MouseSync, 'touch': TouchSync});

    var PageView = require('views/PageView');
    var StripView = require('views/StripView');

    var MenuView = require('views/MenuView');
    var StripData = require('data/StripData');

    function AppView() {
        View.apply(this, arguments);

        this.menuToggle = false;
        this.pageViewPos = new Transitionable(0);
        this.stripViewPos = new Transitionable(0);

        _createPageView.call(this);
        _StripView.call(this);
        _createMenuView.call(this);

        _setListeners.call(this);
        _handleSwipe.call(this);
        _setListenersForStripView.call(this);
    }

    AppView.prototype = Object.create(View.prototype);
    AppView.prototype.constructor = AppView;

    AppView.DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
        openPosition: 276,
        transition: {
            duration: 300,
            curve: 'easeOut'
        },
        posThreshold: 138,
        velThreshold: 0.75
    };

    function _createPageView() {
        this.pageView = new PageView();
        this.pageModifier = new Modifier({
            transform: function() {
                return Transform.translate(this.pageViewPos.get(), 0, 0);
            }.bind(this)
        });

        this._add(this.pageModifier).add(this.pageView);
    }

    function _StripView() {
        this.stripView = new StripView();
          this.stripModifier = new Modifier({
            transform: function() {
                return Transform.translate(this.stripViewPos.get(), 0, 0);
            }.bind(this)
        });

        this._add(this.stripModifier).add(this.stripView);
    }

    function _createMenuView() {
        this.menuView = new MenuView({stripData: StripData});

        var menuModifier = new StateModifier({
            transform: Transform.behind
        });

        this.add(menuModifier).add(this.menuView);
    }

    function _setListeners() {
        this.pageView.on('menuToggle', this.toggleMenu.bind(this));
    }

    function _setListenersForStripView() {
        this.stripView.on('menuToggleforStripView', this.toggleMenu.bind(this));
    }

    function _handleSwipe() {
        var sync = new GenericSync(
                ['mouse', 'touch'],
                {direction: GenericSync.DIRECTION_X}
        );

        this.pageView.pipe(sync);

        sync.on('update', function(data) {
            var currentPosition = this.pageViewPos.get();
            if (currentPosition === 0 && data.velocity > 0) {
                this.menuView.animateStrips();
            }

            this.pageViewPos.set(Math.max(0, currentPosition + data.delta));
        }.bind(this));

        sync.on('end', (function(data) {
            var velocity = data.velocity;
            var position = this.pageViewPos.get();

            if (this.pageViewPos.get() > this.options.posThreshold) {
                if (velocity < -this.options.velThreshold) {
                    this.slideLeft();
                } else {
                    this.slideRight();
                }
            } else {
                if (velocity > this.options.velThreshold) {
                    this.slideRight();
                } else {
                    this.slideLeft();
                }
            }
        }).bind(this));
    }

    AppView.prototype.toggleMenu = function() {
        if (this.menuToggle) {
            this.slideLeft();
        } else {
            this.slideRight();
            this.menuView.animateStrips();
        }
    };

    AppView.prototype.slideLeft = function() {
        this.pageViewPos.set(0, this.options.transition, function() {
            this.menuToggle = false;
        }.bind(this));
    };

    AppView.prototype.slideRight = function() {
        this.pageViewPos.set(this.options.openPosition, this.options.transition, function() {
            this.menuToggle = true;
        }.bind(this));
    };

    module.exports = AppView;
});
```

now what this code does, is create another strip overlapping the previous strips and it only works on the newly created strip view but not on the other strips which means when it comes back to srip view it loads only the DEFAULT_OPTIONS of strip view because the strip which is being generated newly and overlaping is titled famo.us

Please let me know where I am going wrong and how can I open a new view in my application by closing menu drawer.

Comment: I'm mostly not sure whats your code and whats the demos code. So just to clarify do you just want to be able to click one of the menu options and have a new page open and the menu to slide closed?

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a folder named 'data' with the 'StripData.js' file on your famo.us project?

I'm asking because I downloaded the the Starter Kit and I didn't find that file inside.